# Adding DateTime in ADO.NET Entity model at MVC

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net, datepicker

I used ADO.NET Entity Model and retrieved some tables of a database.
Then I created a controller to add,edit,delete data from the tables.
I have some DateTime fields in the table which I want to see as Date Pickers in the interface.
I tried using it like:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> startdate {get;set;}
```

It didn't give me a date-picker and keep showing as a TextBox.
How can I use a date-picker in the ado.net model?
**Is there anyway that I can turn those textboxes into datepickers in the cshtml code?**

**Is there anyway that I can do it using TextBoxFor instead of EditorFor?**
I tried javascript datapicker as well maybe forming it properly will get me the solution:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Baslangic, new { @class = "date" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Bitis, new { @class = "date" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
    });
</script>
```

Gave me  an error saying *"Uncought TypeError:Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use something like the jQuery datepicker to achieve this.

Have a look at the following website: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx

**Update**

You need to add a script section to turn those textboxes into datepickers. This should get you started but ideally you would want to add a class attribute to the textbox and then just use $('.date').datepicker...

Add something like the below.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Baslangic, new { @class = "date" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Bitis, new { @class = "date" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I used it when I created my own models and worked fine:
  [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
But now I doesn't seem to be working with a ADO.NET model still.

Comment: Have a look at the rendered HTML and see why the jQuery datepicker may not be applying to the textbox. Post the output of the html and your jquery datepicker call.

Comment: I updated my question.Do you know how to do it using html.textboxfor?

Comment: Thanks.I added those lines at the beginning of my code.
Could you help me apply those to **"TextBoxFor"**s?**@Html.TextBoxForModel(x => x.Created, new { @class = "date" })**
Is this the way?

Comment: It should just be Html.TextBoxFor(x => x...) - I've updated my answer for clarification.

Comment: My code is here unfortunately not working,is there anywhere to correct? :
`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
        
    });

</script>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <table>...<some "tr"s and "td"s here>
<td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Baslangic, new {@class="date" }) 
 `

Comment: Looks fine to me. I would recommend using fiddler to make sure your jquery libraries are loading up. Then use some debugger such as firebug (mozilla), chrome as an inbuilt debugger to see if there are any javascript errors.

Comment: Here is the javascript error for the line `$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });`: _Uncought TypeError:Object [object Object] has no method 'datepicker'_

Comment: Jquery datepicker is part of the jquery UI package. Make sure you also have a script pointing to jquery ui. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I pasted the code below under `<script src=".....min.js">` lines
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />`
The error is : _Failed to load source_ **Js and Css files are failed.**

Comment: Found the answer.Thanks for your help.It guided me well to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!
1- Make user you follow the directions at http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/
Here is my code to do it with cshtml.Put this at the beginning

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
```

and then type the following

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker();

    });
</script>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Baslangic, new {@class="datepicker" })
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Baslangic, new {@class="datepicker" })
```